# How to most efficiently use QR-decomposition in Julia?

Tags: performance, julia, linear-algebra, qr-decomposition

Avoiding array allocations is good for performance. However, I have yet to understand what is the most possible efficient way one can perform a QR decomposition of a matrix `A`. (note: both Q and R matrices are needed)

Simply using

`Q, R = qr(A)`

is probably not the best idea, since it allocates both Q and R, where both could be re-allocated.

The function `qrfact` allows one to [store factorization in a packed format](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg.html#Base.LinAlg.qrfact). However, I would still write afterwards:

`F = qrfact(A); Q = F[:Q]; R = F[:R]`

once again allocating new arrays for `Q` and `R`. Finally, the documentation also suggests the `qrfact!` function, which [saves space by overwriting the input A, instead of creating a copy](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg.html#Base.LinAlg.qrfact!). However, if one uses `F = qrfact!(A)`
the over-written `A` is not *useful* in the sense that it is not either `Q` or `R`, which one (specifically, I) would need.

So my two questions are:

1. What is the best/most efficient way to perform a QR decomposition if you only care about the matrices `Q` and `R` and you have no problem re-allocating them.
2. What is actually written in the matrix `A` when one calls `qrfact!(A)` ?

Comment: Why do you need to do `Q = F[:Q]; R = F[:R]` afterwards? Can't you just use `F[:Q]` as it is?

Comment: There are references to the storage method in the Julia documentation. Specifically this [paper](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/A%20Storage-Efficient%20WY%20Representation%20for%20Products%20of%20Householder%20Transformations.pdf) was linked to. But in fact, you would want to look at this [julia code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/82e96382251a1e163860df03c846acec86d07c36/base/linalg/qr.jl#L43-L87)

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard It doesn't matter for me if I use `Q` or `F[:Q]`. The issue is how to avoid the allocation done from `F[:Q]` (if any is done).

Comment: Oh damn, unfortunately I need to operate on the `F[:Q]` matrix because I need to change sign on some of the columns (qr-decomposition to find lyapunov exponents)

Comment: I have some *serious* doubts that the cost to allocate an array (effectively O(1)) is even detectable in an algorithm that involves performing the O(n^3) QR decomposition. Have you profiled your code and verified that you actually need to avoid these allocations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
F = qrfact!(A)
```

or

```
F = qrfact(A)
```

`F[:Q]` and `F[:R]` do not allocate new dense arrays; they are simply views over the packed format from which `Q` and `R` are easily computed. This means that `qrfact!(A)` doesn't need to allocate arrays for `Q` and `R`, it simply computes the packed format in place for `A`.

However, that also means that `F[:Q]` and `F[:R]` *cannot be mutated*. If you need to modify one of them for whatever reason, you will need to `collect` it into a mutable `Array`, and this will certainly allocate. It will still be more efficient to use `qrfact!(A)` instead of `qrfact(A)`, because the latter will allocate space for the packed QR factorization as well as for the `collect`ed `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After looking around more I also came to the same conclusion (`F[:Q]` doesn't allocate). I've also understood what `qrfact!(A)` does to `A`: It has the same elements as `R`, but it is not upper-triagonal, so I don't know whats going on with the lower triangle though.

P.s.: No I have not found this to be the reason my code is slow. It was simply an opportunity for me to get a better understanding of how to use `qr` with Julia.

Comment: The format we use to store the QR factorization is described in http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d9a/group__double_g_ecomputational_ga3ad112f2b0890b3815e696628906f30c.html#ga3ad112f2b0890b3815e696628906f30c so basically, `Q` is stored in the lower triangle and the extra `T` matrix.